# Stack function supposed to return a specified element, instead returns garbage value

Tags: c++, stack, garbage

```
int getElement(stack<int> s,int i){
if(i>1){
   s.pop();
   getElement(s,i-1);
   }
else
    return  s.top();
}

int main(){
    stack<int> pancakes;
    pancakes.push(1);
    pancakes.push(2);
    pancakes.push(3);
    printf("%d",getElement(pancakes,2));


 }
```

Help! My getElement function returns the element at i where i starts from the top value of the stack with the value of 1.

When I run getElement(2), it should return 2 on a stack:
3 - index 1,
2 - index 2 and
1 - index 3

it prints garbage value. Assume it only accepts values that are acceptable (index is within bounds), error handling is something I'll do later.

Comment: Read your function carefully, and tell me what it returns if `i` does not equal 1.

Comment: This does not compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `return` statement.

Change

```
int getElement(stack<int> s,int i){
if(i!=1){
   s.pop();
   getElement(s,i-1);
   }
else
    return  s.top();
}
```

to

```
int getElement(stack<int> s,int i){
if(i!=1){
   s.pop();
   return getElement(s,i-1); // The line with the missing return.
   }
else
    return  s.top();
}
```

Comment: Exactly why compiler warnings should be on.

Comment: Thanks so much! I've been away from C++ for along while now that I forgot how recursion works T_T. Thanks again!

Comment: @NolanDeogracias It's an easy mistake to make in C/C++ if you have been a language like Scheme where the value of the last expression is the return value.